# R unresolved variable when duplicating activities

Tags: android, duplicates, code-duplication

I am attempting to duplicate my project with a different title and package name. However, when I copy and paste the activities, it returns that R is an unresolved variable that I can either import from android or from my package. Is there a better way to copy my project or is there a way to resolve R?

Comment: In addition to referring to R in the right package namespace, sometimes you have to clean the project to trigger it to be rebuilt in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

if you changed your package name you have also to change it in the 
AndroidManifest.xml

You can copy paste your project on your disk and on your project on eclipse  right click on your package and go to refactor --> rename

Comment: @Cole did you import android.R in one of your class, did you get errors in your res folder?

Comment: you can cpy paste your project on your disk and use Right click on your project on eclipse and right click on your packages-->refactor-->rename

Answer (score 0):

Just delete all your import statements that say

import com.you.yourapp.R

and finish creating your new project. The problem will fix itself.

EDIT

Just read why you are doing this. An easier way would be to right click the package in the original project, go to refactor>rename and just rename the package. Then update your AndroidManifest with the new package name and application title.